# Computed field in Servicestack ormlite error

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I couldn't make it work, I added the `data annotation` for a `computed field` using `ServiceStack ormlite Sql server`:

```
[Compute, Ignore]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

The problem is that my `LoadSelect<Employee>()` method doesn't load the colunm FullName from a `computed` field. Why?

if I remove the `[Ignore]` it loads, but then when I use the`.create()` method to create a new record, it returns an error, probably because it tries to add a value for the FullName field.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FullName]  AS (concat(ltrim(rtrim([FirstName])),' ',ltrim(rtrim([LastName])))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](55) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](55) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](55) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Employee class:**

```
[Schema("dbo")]
[Alias("Employee")]
public class Employee : IHasId<int>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Alias("EmployeeId")]
    [AutoIncrement]
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public int Id { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compute, Ignore]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**Get method:**

```
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get<T>() where T : IHasId<int>
    {
        using (var dbCon = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            return await dbCon.LoadSelectAsync<T>(x => x);
        }
    }
```

**Create method:**

```
    public virtual async Task<T> Create<T>(T obj) where T: IHasId<int>
    {
        using (var dbCon = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            // if there is an id then INSERTS otherwise UPDATES
            var id = obj.GetId().SafeToLong();

            if (id > 0)
                dbCon.Update(obj);
            else
                id = dbCon.Insert(obj, true);   

            // returns the object inserted or updated
            return await dbCon.LoadSingleByIdAsync<T>(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about use of `.create()`? This a custom wrapper using `Db.Insert<T>` underneath or other? Also if you could provide full example POCOs for `LoadSelect` so others can reproduce issue?

Comment: Yes, does the information help? @Layoric

Comment: @RogerOliveira no it's still not runnable, it's missing the definition of `Employee` Table and can you also provide the CREATE TABLE definition of Employee you're using that has the Computed column so we can test it locally?

Comment: @mythz I have removed a few fields of child tables and updated the info in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[Ignore]` attribute tells OrmLite you want it to ignore the property completely which is not what you want, you need to just use the `[Compute]` attribute to handle computed columns which I've just [added a test for in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/14bded8e0633c21bc7a28b0c4d62d43d156467ab) which is working as expected in the latest version of OrmLite, e.g:

```
db.DropTable<Employee>();
db.ExecuteSql(@"
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
[EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FullName]  AS (concat(ltrim(rtrim([FirstName])),' ',ltrim(rtrim([LastName])))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](55) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
[Username] [nvarchar](55) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](55) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeId] ASC)");

var item = new Employee
{
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName",
    Username = "Username",
    Password = "Password",
    FullName = "Should be ignored",
};

var id = db.Insert(item, selectIdentity: true);

var row = db.LoadSingleById<ComputeTest>(id);

Assert.That(row.FirstName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName"));
Assert.That(row.FullName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName LastName"));

row.LastName = "Updated LastName";
db.Update(row);

row = db.LoadSingleById<ComputeTest>(id);

Assert.That(row.FirstName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName"));
Assert.That(row.FullName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName Updated LastName"));
```

Which also works using the async API's in your `Create()` helper method, e.g:

```
var row = await Create(item);

Assert.That(row.FirstName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName"));
Assert.That(row.FullName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName LastName"));

row.LastName = "Updated LastName";
row = await Create(row);

Assert.That(row.FirstName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName"));
Assert.That(row.FullName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName Updated LastName"));
```

I'm assuming you're using an older version of OrmLite, if you upgrade to the latest version it should work.

Comment: the new version of Service Stack 4.0.60  changed the method params. I can't use dbCon.LoadSelect<Account>(x => x) why? also the .OrderBy(x => x.Field) is not working

Comment: @RogerOliveira Those API's didn't change [unless you're using the deprecated versions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.60.md#cleaner-modernized-api-surface), it sounds like you got a dirty build. Make sure all packages are upgraded to v4.0.60 and do a clean/rebuild, if that doesn't work try restarting VS.NET.

Comment: what about the: LoadSelectAsync this one doesn't work as usual: await dbCon.LoadSelectAsync<Account>(y => y.IsActive).OrderBy(y => y.AccountName);

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression<Next.Management.Core.Model.Task.Account>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I could make it working converting this way: await dbCon.LoadSelectAsync(dbCon.From<Account>().Where(y => y.IsActive).OrderBy(y => y.AccountName))

Comment: @RogerOliveira See this commit for [different Async API Usage examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/583ec7afc1d1c3396d3361636c86caa4d940de94)

Comment: I have another issue, now as I've removed the [Ignore] attribute, i have this error: Invalid column name 'Duration'. how can I ignore this field when my query doesn't bring the duration column, but uses it when it brings. some one attribute such as [Optional] ?

Comment: @RogerOliveira I've no idea what you mean, please open a new question containing the POCO definition, the SQL CREATE Table schema (if it wasn't created with OrmLite) and the source code that has the issue.

Comment: @mythz I think that the problem of Roger Oliveira is that Select() method (without any parameter) generates a table field even if it is marked with [Computed]. I have the same problem.